# Thesis V3.bbl: 72: Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence

Tags: bibtex, input-encodings, texshop, bbl

I am writing my thesis and the preamble looks as the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis} % ,manychapters

%\usepackage[osf]{libertine}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{epigraph}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amstext}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{theoremref}

\usepackage{amsrefs}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{dirtytalk}

\usepackage{csquotes}
.

.

.
```

I use `\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}` to run the bibliography ( the file name is thesis.bib). Everything runs smoothly when I run it in the overleaf. When I run it in the texshop (on my mac), the first run of latex goes smoothly (of course the bibliography doesn't load). Then, I run the bibtex to parse the .bib file. But, when I do the second run of latex, I get the following error message:

Thesis V3.bbl: 72: Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8  byte sequence.

What should I do to fix it?
Thank you for all the help and comments!!

Comment: presumably the bib file is not in UTF-8  check its encoding in your editor. You can tell which entry in the bib file by seeing which entry in the generated bbl is giving the error.

Comment: What should I do to fix it?

Comment: you haven't really given much information but it may be as simple as loading the .bib file into your editor and saving it  in utf-8 (I can't tell you how to do that in texshop but most editors will have such a function)

Comment: or simply discard the files you have and download the project again from overleaf.

Comment: I see. Thank you!!